# How do I run PHP Content in a Django Website

Tags: php, python, django, ipb

I want to port over most of my current website from PHP to Python/Django.

However, I would like to keep the forums the same as I paid for the forums (IPBoard). The forums work off of PHP.

Is there anyway I can still have my forums running on PHP and the rest of my site on Pyhton/Django?

For example...

If I visit mysite.com/ it would be running my python/django code.

However, if I visit mysite.com/forums or mysite.com/forums/whatever it would run the php section of the site for the forums...

Comment: Yes, I've done this before. It requires having Apache/nginx serve PHP in one location, but mod_wsgi/uWSGI/Gunicorn/etc in another. This is a question for Serverfault, though.

Comment: Surely a simple alias in your webserver config file is enough to handle this

Comment: @MarkIgnacio don't suppose you were able to make some kind of guide or know of one?